# Using Linq to order multiple lists from multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

At the moment, I have multiple tables in my Database with slightly varying columns to define different "history" elements for an item.

So I have my item table;

```
int ItemId {get;set}
string Name {get;set}
Location Loc {get;set}    
int Quantity {get;set}
```

I can do a few things to these items like Move, Increase Quantity, Decrease Quantity, Book to a Customer, "Pick" an item, things like that. So I have made multiple "History Tables" as they have different values to save E.g

```
 public class MoveHistory
 {
    public int MoveHistoryId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location2Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class PickingHistory
 {
    public int PickingHistoryId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public int WorksOrderCode { get; set; }
 }
```

This is fine apart from where I want to show a complete history for an item displayed in a list;

> Item 123 was moved on 23/02/2013 from Location1 to Location2
>
> Item 123 was picked on 24/02/2013 from work order 421

I am using Entity Framework, .NET 4.5, WPF, and querying using Linq but cannot figure a way of taking these lists of history elements, and ordering them out one by one based on their date.

I can think of messy ways, like one single history table with columns used if required. Or even create a third list containing the date and what list it came from, then cycle through that list picking the corresponding contents from the corresponding list. However, I feel there must be a better way!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a `GetDescription()` method on your history items (even as an extension method), you can do this:

```
db.PickingHistory.Where(ph => ph.Item.ItemId == 123)
    .Select(ph => new { Time = ph.Date, Description = ph.GetDescription() })
.Concat(db.MoveHistory.Where(mh => mh.ItemId == 123)
    .Select(mh => new { Time = mh.Date, Description = mh.GetDescription() })
.OrderByDescending(e => e.Time).Select(e => e.Description);
```

Comment: THIS is the kind of thing I was after. Ryan Amies probably describes the neatest solution, but this is the thing I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea why I am getting the error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetDescription()'? Im sure it has something to do with the description method I added to the history classes, and Entity Framework not liking it. May be an unrelated question

Comment: You're right -- it looks very much like an issue with ESQL to me.  Unfortunately, its error messages can be rather misleading.  The simplest thing I can suggest is to comment out all of the lines in `GetDescription()` and replace them with something trivial, then reinstate them until you find the point of failure.  That's how I dealt with ESQL woes the last time I came up against this kind of thing.

Comment: By the way, I'm just going to make a small edit to my answer to make it more readable.  No substantive changes though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you're trying to use your database model as a display model and obviously are failing. You need to create a new class that represents your history grid and then populate it from your various queries. From your example output the display model may be:

```
public class HistoryRow{
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

You then load the data into this display model:

```
var historyRows = new List<HistoryRow>();

var pickingRows = _db.PickingHistory.Select(ph => new HistoryRow{
    EventDate = ph.Date,
    ItemName = ph.Item.Name,
    Action = "picked",
    Detail = "from works order " + ph.WorksOrderCode);
historyRows.AddRange(pickingRows);

var movingRows = _db.MoveHistory.Select(mh => new HistoryRow{
    EventDate = mh.Date,
    ItemName = ph.Item.Name,
    Action = "moved",
    Detail = "from location " + mh.Location1Id + " to location " + mh.Location2Id);
historyRows.AddRange(movingRows );
```

You can repeatedly add the rows from various tables to get a big list of the `HistoryRow` actions and then order that list and display the values as you wish.

```
foreach(var historyRow in historyRows)
{
    var rowAsString = historyRow.ItemName + " was " + historyRow.Action.....;
    Console.WriteLine(rowAsString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing this in order to provide some sort of undo/redo history, then I think that you're going about it in the wrong way. Normally, you would have one collection of `ICommand` objects with associated parameter values, eg. you store the operations that have occurred. You would then be able to filter this collection for each item individually.

If you're not trying to implement some sort of undo/redo history, then I have misunderstood your question and you can ignore this.